# Error: Sorry we are unable to provide this at the mom

Tags: database, search, mysql

CiviCRM 4.6
WordPress 4.8.1

This is a brand new installation with one record in the contacts table. When I did a search I got this error. There are no custom fields.

More error details:

```
Database Error Code: Expression #37 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'wp_thecivithing.civicrm_address.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by, 1055
Additional Details:
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`, contact_a.contact_sub_type  as `contact_sub_type`, contact_a.sort_name  as `sort_name`, contact_a.display_name  as `display_name`, contact_a.do_not_email  as `do_not_email`, contact_a.do_not_phone  as `do_not_phone`, contact_a.do_not_mail  as `do_not_mail`, contact_a.do_not_sms  as `do_not_sms`, contact_a.do_not_trade  as `do_not_trade`, contact_a.is_opt_out  as `is_opt_out`, contact_a.legal_identifier  as `legal_identifier`, contact_a.external_identifier  as `external_identifier`, contact_a.nick_name  as `nick_name`, contact_a.legal_name  as `legal_name`, contact_a.image_URL  as `image_URL`, contact_a.preferred_communication_method  as `preferred_communication_method`, contact_a.preferred_language  as `preferred_language`, contact_a.preferred_mail_format  as `preferred_mail_format`, contact_a.first_name  as `first_name`, contact_a.middle_name  as `middle_name`, contact_a.last_name  as `last_name`, contact_a.prefix_id  as `prefix_id`, contact_a.suffix_id  as `suffix_id`, contact_a.formal_title  as `formal_title`, contact_a.communication_style_id  as `communication_style_id`, contact_a.job_title  as `job_title`, contact_a.gender_id  as `gender_id`, contact_a.birth_date  as `birth_date`, contact_a.is_deceased  as `is_deceased`, contact_a.deceased_date  as `deceased_date`, contact_a.household_name  as `household_name`, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', NULL, contact_a.organization_name ) as organization_name, contact_a.sic_code  as `sic_code`, contact_a.is_deleted  as `contact_is_deleted`, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', contact_a.organization_name, NULL ) as current_employer, civicrm_address.id as address_id, civicrm_address.street_address as `street_address`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_1 as `supplemental_address_1`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_2 as `supplemental_address_2`, civicrm_address.city as `city`, civicrm_address.postal_code_suffix as `postal_code_suffix`, civicrm_address.postal_code as `postal_code`, civicrm_address.geo_code_1 as `geo_code_1`, civicrm_address.geo_code_2 as `geo_code_2`, civicrm_address.state_province_id as state_province_id, civicrm_address.country_id as country_id, civicrm_phone.id as phone_id, civicrm_phone.phone_type_id as phone_type_id, civicrm_phone.phone as `phone`, civicrm_email.id as email_id, civicrm_email.email as `email`, civicrm_email.on_hold as `on_hold`, civicrm_im.id as im_id, civicrm_im.provider_id as provider_id, civicrm_im.name as `im`, civicrm_worldregion.id as worldregion_id, civicrm_worldregion.name as `world_region`  FROM civicrm_prevnext_cache pnc INNER JOIN civicrm_contact contact_a ON contact_a.id = pnc.entity_id1 AND pnc.cacheKey = 'civicrm search e6d5a7db1a38e03b5d819b941e64dda2_6120'  LEFT JOIN civicrm_address ON ( contact_a.id = civicrm_address.contact_id AND civicrm_address.is_primary = 1 ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_email ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_email.contact_id AND civicrm_email.is_primary = 1)  LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_phone.contact_id AND civicrm_phone.is_primary = 1)  LEFT JOIN civicrm_im ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_im.contact_id AND civicrm_im.is_primary = 1)  LEFT JOIN civicrm_country ON civicrm_address.country_id = civicrm_country.id  LEFT JOIN civicrm_worldregion ON civicrm_country.region_id = civicrm_worldregion.id  WHERE (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)  GROUP BY contact_a.id  ORDER BY pnc.id  LIMIT 0, 50 [nativecode=1055 ** Expression #37 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'wp_thecivithing.civicrm_address.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`, contact_a.contact_sub_type  as `contact_sub_type`, contact_a.sort_name  as `sort_name`, contact_a.display_name  as `display_name`, contact_a.do_not_email  as `do_not_email`, contact_a.do_not_phone  as `do_not_phone`, contact_a.do_not_mail  as `do_not_mail`, contact_a.do_not_sms  as `do_not_sms`, contact_a.do_not_trade  as `do_not_trade`, contact_a.is_opt_out  as `is_opt_out`, contact_a.legal_identifier  as `legal_identifier`, contact_a.external_identifier  as `external_identifier`, contact_a.nick_name  as `nick_name`, contact_a.legal_name  as `legal_name`, contact_a.image_URL  as `image_URL`, contact_a.preferred_communication_method  as `preferred_communication_method`, contact_a.preferred_language  as `preferred_language`, contact_a.preferred_mail_format  as `preferred_mail_format`, contact_a.first_name  as `first_name`, contact_a.middle_name  as `middle_name`, contact_a.last_name  as `last_name`, contact_a.prefix_id  as `prefix_id`, contact_a.suffix_id  as `suffix_id`, contact_a.formal_title  as `formal_title`, contact_a.communication_style_id  as `communication_style_id`, contact_a.job_title  as `job_title`, contact_a.gender_id  as `gender_id`, contact_a.birth_date  as `birth_date`, contact_a.is_deceased  as `is_deceased`, contact_a.deceased_date  as `deceased_date`, contact_a.household_name  as `household_name`, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', NULL, contact_a.organization_name ) as organization_name, contact_a.sic_code  as `sic_code`, contact_a.is_deleted  as `contact_is_deleted`, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', contact_a.organization_name, NULL ) as current_employer, civicrm_address.id as address_id, civicrm_address.street_address as `street_address`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_1 as `supplemental_address_1`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_2 as `supplemental_address_2`, civicrm_address.city as `city`, civicrm_address.postal_code_suffix as `postal_code_suffix`, civicrm_address.postal_code as `postal_code`, civicrm_address.geo_code_1 as `geo_code_1`, civicrm_address.geo_code_2 as `geo_code_2`, civicrm_address.state_province_id as state_province_id, civicrm_address.country_id as country_id, civicrm_phone.id as phone_id, civicrm_phone.phone_type_id as phone_type_id, civicrm_phone.phone as `phone`, civicrm_email.id as email_id, civicrm_email.email as `email`, civicrm_email.on_hold as `on_hold`, civicrm_im.id as im_id, civicrm_im.provider_id as provider_id, civicrm_im.name as `im`, civicrm_worldregion.id as worldregion_id, civicrm_worldregion.name as `world_region`  FROM civicrm_prevnext_cache pnc INNER JOIN civicrm_contact contact_a ON contact_a.id = pnc.entity_id1 AND pnc.cacheKey = 'civicrm search e6d5a7db1a38e03b5d819b941e64dda2_6120'  LEFT JOIN civicrm_address ON ( contact_a.id = civicrm_address.contact_id AND civicrm_address.is_primary = 1 ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_email ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_email.contact_id AND civicrm_email.is_primary = 1)  LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_phone.contact_id AND civicrm_phone.is_primary = 1)  LEFT JOIN civicrm_im ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_im.contact_id AND civicrm_im.is_primary = 1)  LEFT JOIN civicrm_country ON civicrm_address.country_id = civicrm_country.id  LEFT JOIN civicrm_worldregion ON civicrm_country.region_id = civicrm_worldregion.id  WHERE (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)  GROUP BY contact_a.id  ORDER BY pnc.id  LIMIT 0, 50 [nativecode=1055 ** Expression #37 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'wp_thecivithing.civicrm_address.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`, contact_a.contact_sub_type  as `contact_sub_type`, contact_a.sort_name  as `sort_name`, contact_a.display_name  as `display_name`, contact_a.do_not_email  as `do_not_email`, contact_a.do_not_phone  as `do_not_phone`, contact_a.do_not_mail  as `do_not_mail`, contact_a.do_not_sms  as `do_not_sms`, contact_a.do_not_trade  as `do_not_trade`, contact_a.is_opt_out  as `is_opt_out`, contact_a.legal_identifier  as `legal_identifier`, contact_a.external_identifier  as `external_identifier`, contact_a.nick_name  as `nick_name`, contact_a.legal_name  as `legal_name`, contact_a.image_URL  as `image_URL`, contact_a.preferred_communication_method  as `preferred_communication_method`, contact_a.preferred_language  as `preferred_language`, contact_a.preferred_mail_format  as `preferred_mail_format`, contact_a.first_name  as `first_name`, contact_a.middle_name  as `middle_name`, contact_a.last_name  as `last_name`, contact_a.prefix_id  as `prefix_id`, contact_a.suffix_id  as `suffix_id`, contact_a.formal_title  as `formal_title`, contact_a.communication_style_id  as `communication_style_id`, contact_a.job_title  as `job_title`, contact_a.gender_id  as `gender_id`, contact_a.birth_date  as `birth_date`, contact_a.is_deceased  as `is_deceased`, contact_a.deceased_date  as `deceased_date`, contact_a.household_name  as `household_name`, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', NULL, contact_a.organization_name ) as organization_name, contact_a.sic_code  as `sic_code`, contact_a.is_deleted  as `contact_is_deleted`, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', contact_a.organization_name, NULL ) as current_employer, civicrm_address.id as address_id, civicrm_address.street_address as `street_address`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_1 as `supplemental_address_1`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_2 as `supplemental_address_2`, civicrm_address.city as `city`, civicrm_address.postal_code_suffix as `postal_code_suffix`, civicrm_address.postal_code as `postal_code`, civicrm_address.geo_code_1 as `geo_code_1`, civicrm_address.geo_code_2 as `geo_code_2`, civicrm_address.state_province_id as state_province_id, civicrm_address.country_id as country_id, civicrm_phone.id as phone_id, civicrm_phone.phone_type_id as phone_type_id, civicrm_phone.phone as `phone`, civicrm_email.id as email_id, civicrm_email.email as `email`, civicrm_email.on_hold as `on_hold`, civicrm_im.id as im_id, civicrm_im.provider_id as provider_id, civicrm_im.name as `im`, civicrm_worldregion.id as worldregion_id, civicrm_worldregion.name as `world_region`  FROM civicrm_prevnext_cache pnc INNER JOIN civicrm_contact contact_a ON contact_a.id = pnc.entity_id1 AND pnc.cacheKey = 'civicrm search e6d5a7db1a38e03b5d819b941e64dda2_6120'  LEFT JOIN civicrm_address ON ( contact_a.id = civicrm_address.contact_id AND civicrm_address.is_primary = 1 ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_email ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_email.contact_id AND civicrm_email.is_primary = 1)  LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_phone.contact_id AND civicrm_phone.is_primary = 1)  LEFT JOIN civicrm_im ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_im.contact_id AND civicrm_im.is_primary = 1)  LEFT JOIN civicrm_country ON civicrm_address.country_id = civicrm_country.id  LEFT JOIN civicrm_worldregion ON civicrm_country.region_id = civicrm_worldregion.id  WHERE (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)  GROUP BY contact_a.id  ORDER BY pnc.id  LIMIT 0, 50 [nativecode=1055 ** Expression #37 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'wp_thecivithing.civicrm_address.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by]"]
)
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: See also https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/13117/suscpicious-database-errors?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

are you using mysql 5.7?

There were a number of issues that came up for folks switching from 5.5 to 5.7

I think many (most? all?) were fixed in 4.7 but that has not been backported to 4.6

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18439?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true

you might want to look at disabling mysql's ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY option

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033983